# Where is the Windows Azure SQL Reporting Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-reporting

According to the MSDN documentation for [Windows Azure SQL Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403967.aspx), the reporting portal is supposed to be accessible from the main Azure portal:

> The Windows Azure Management Portal includes portals for Windows Azure SQL Database, SQL Reporting and other services available on Windows Azure. From the portal home page, click Reporting to launch the SQL Reporting management portal

This seems to be referring to the old Azure portal. At any rate, my portal doesn't have such a link. All I see are

- web sites
- vitual machines
- cloud services
- sql databases
- storage
- networks
- service bus
- media services
- active directory
- add-ons
- settings

I've used the search feature to search the Azure portal, checked out my SQL Azure database server configuration, and generally poked around for quite a while but I can't find any way to get to the reporting portal. How can get there and/or activate this feature?

Comment: [SQL Reporting will discontinue service on October 31, 2014.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-reporting/)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It's a pity the Azure SQL Reporting team didn't give non-insane pricing a try. That might have made a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Azure portal currently uses new HTML version. You have to switch to old Silverlight version.

To go back to the old portal, you have to click on your account (top right) and click on "Previous Portal"

[image: Previous Portal]

### EDIT

`Previous portal` option is no longer there. Windows Azure are preparing brand new portal. Similarly to the current one, it will be using HTML5 and JavaScript - not [Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) technology.

[image: Azure Preview Portal]

Comment: A note on this for anyone reading this now; the HTML portal does now provide management of Azure SQL Reporting Services.  [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh403967.aspx)

Comment: not coming now, they have again changed it and now this option is not coming in new portal.