# Is SQL Reporting Services available with Azure or any other azure newly introduced reporting services?

Tags: sql, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I would like to know if Azure has introduced any Reporting tool corresponding to SQL Reporting Services or even if it does support  SQL reporting services in cloud flavour like other newly introduce Azure services.

I have a database hosted on Azure SQL and would like to run some reports on it. I have checked some links ([SSRS vs Azure SQL Reporting - Cost and Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965580/ssrs-vs-azure-sql-reporting-cost-and-implementation)) saying that this feature (Windows Azure Reporting Services) has been discontinued but couldn't find any link confirming it from Microsoft.

I would like to know if Azure does support creating reports from Azure SQL tables or Am I supposed to create a traditional Virtual Machine with SQL and reporting services running.

Please let me know the best/feasible approach.

Thanks in advance!

Libin

Comment: It is now supported in SSRS 2017

Answer (score 8):

Reporting Services has been updated in SQL Server 2016, but it is not a standalone service in Azure. If you want a cloud based reporting service, you will need to create a VM that hosts the reporting server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I assume this was an option before and got discontinued- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288188/where-is-the-windows-azure-sql-reporting-portal

Comment: Yes that would have been an option, but it was discontinued several years ago.